# How can I exclude the @ptr field from my CloudWatch Logs Insights query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have this AWS CloudWatch query, that I've created via the AWS CLI with `aws logs start-query`:

```
display @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp asc
| filter @message not like "GET / HTTP/1.1"'
```

When using `aws logs get-query-results`, this query returns `@timestamp` & `@message` as needed but also an extra `@ptr` field.

How can I change my query to not return the `@ptr` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change my query to not return the `@ptr` field?

You can't filter out the `@ptr` field server-side as it's returned by [`GetQueryResults`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueryResults.html) at the API level as the log record identifier & there's no option to exclude it from the results.

---

Client-side however, some `jq` magic can remove the `ptr` field from the AWS CLI output.

Try:

```bash
aws logs get-query-results \
--query-id 'xxx' \
| jq 'del(.results[][] | select(.field == "@ptr"))'
```

This filter tells `jq` to delete all objects in each array within `results`, where `field` is equal to `@ptr`.

---

Output before filtering:

```json
{
  "results": [
    [
      {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "value": "2023-09-25 22:41:44.378"
      },
      {
        "field": "@message",
        "value": "END RequestId: 69cdac96-c8d1-4935-94e4-6ce45acc4935\n"
      },
      {
        "field": "@ptr",
        "value": "Cl0KIAocNTg1NDcwMzQ2NjkyOi9hd3MvbGFtYmRhL2FhYRADEjUaGAIGUHTBkwAAAAAkeektAAZRIMOgAAACMiABKIDihfSsMTC644X0rDE4BUDRBUjiD1DpCBgAIAEQAxgB"
      }
    ]
  ],
  ...
}
```

Output after filtering via `jq`:

```json
{
  "results": [
    [
      {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "value": "2023-09-25 22:41:44.378"
      },
      {
        "field": "@message",
        "value": "END RequestId: 69cdac96-c8d1-4935-94e4-6ce45acc4935\n"
      }
    ]
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm using Nushell so I removed the `@ptr` field after getting the result but I wondered if it was possible to removed directly from the query, sad to have the confirmation I can't do it.